# Spoiler on button

Tags: javascript, button

I'm trying to make spoiler on button. 
It works well only on JSFIddle.
But It doesn't work in HTML document:

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/As6JA/)

**HTML:**

```
<button  onclick="showSpoiler(this);" style="outline: none;" >Spoiler</button>

<span class="inner" style="display:none;">
   This is a spoiler!
</span>
```

**JS**

```
window.showSpoiler = function (obj)
{
    var inner = obj.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("span")[0];       
    if (inner.style.display == "none")
    {     
        obj.style.display = "none";   
        inner.style.display = "";
    }
    else
        inner.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Comment: Define "it doesn't work".

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/k5d98/ Here's the fiddle. Please, be more specific in your problem. Any error? Any misbehavior in the app? Any detail can help us help you .D

Comment: As I told before. It works well in jsfiddle. But in html document there is no any action. Nothing happens when you click on the button

Comment: have you tried without the window. ?

Comment: yes .  Check on my test website http://sunrisetemplate.besaba.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem:**
You do not have any `<span>` element on your website, and your spoiler `onclick` is searching for that. With `inner.style.display` you are trying to access the `style` property of `inner` (which is `undefined` as it could not be found), and hence are getting an error.

**Solution:**

Change
`var inner = obj.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("span")[0];`
to
`var inner = obj.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("div")[0];`

Hope it helps!